# When dynamically creating DropDownButton - it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

When creating a DropDownButton through a class, the dropdown list itself does not open. Tell me, what is my mistake?

The button is in the "inactive" state. That is, when I click on it, I do not have a list with data

**Yes, I'm sure the data is there.**

I would not create a class for the button, but I have about 10 of them, and in order not to have a lot of repetitive code, I need to use the class

I can provide button code -

```
class DropDownButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic valueDropDown;
  final String hintDropDown;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>? itemsDropDown;
  final void Function(dynamic)? saveState;

  const DropDownButtons({
    Key? key,
    required this.valueDropDown,
    required this.hintDropDown,
    required this.itemsDropDown,
    required this.saveState
}) : super (key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 270,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
           
                hint: Text('hintDropDown'),
                value: valueDropDown,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: itemsDropDown,
                onChanged: saveState,
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And also, the display code -

```
      DropDownButtons(valueDropDown: LoginClass.countryValue, hintDropDown: 'Text', itemsDropDown: LoginClass.countryDropDown, saveState: saveStateCountry()),
```

And of course, saving the stat -

```
saveStateCountry() {
    (dynamic newValue) {
      setState(() {
        LoginClass.countryValue = newValue!;
        print(LoginClass.countryValue);
      });
    };
  }
```

***minimum reproductive code -***

```
class CreatedApplications extends StatelessWidget {

  const CreatedApplications({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  saveStateCountry() {
        (dynamic newValue) {
      setState(() {
        LoginClass.countryValue = newValue!;
        print(LoginClass.countryValue);
      });
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Column(children: [
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 1,
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text('${now}'))),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              // const DropDown(),
              DropDownButtons(valueDropDown: LoginClass.countryValue, hintDropDown: 'Выберите страну', itemsDropDown: LoginClass.countryDropDown, saveState: saveStateCountry()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

class DropDownButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic valueDropDown;
  final String hintDropDown;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>? itemsDropDown;
  final Function saveState;

  const DropDownButtons({
    Key? key,
    required this.valueDropDown,
    required this.hintDropDown,
    required this.itemsDropDown,
    required this.saveState
  }) : super (key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 270,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    fillColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.2),
                    filled: true
                ),
                hint: Text(hintDropDown),
                value: valueDropDown,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: itemsDropDown,
                onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
                  saveState;
                }
            )
        )
    );
  

}
}
```

Comment: post the minimal, reproductive code to test your issue

Comment: @pskink done, you can check

Comment: What's `LoginClass.countryDropDown` ?

Comment: There is data for the button - 
` LoginClass.countryDropDown .add(DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(value: resp['data'][i]['id'].toString(), child: Text(resp['data'][i ]['attributes']['country_name']))),`

Comment: i did not test your exact code but most likely `saveStateCountry()` was a culprit

Comment: Indeed, the reason was in it.
But, I still don't understand why it's right now and how it works

Comment: saveState(value), how does the program understand what the value is there?

Comment: `saveState: _saveState,` is used since `saveState` parameter needs a function that accepts one parameter and that function is called here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ffccd96b62/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L1323 - you can set a breakpoint inside `_saveState` and check from where it was called